# Import modules in the AppModule for separation of concerns in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-modules

Templates like from the [ASP.NET Core JavaScript services](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) came with a single module called `AppModule`. Since my application is divided into two logical areas, It seems a good idea to use two modules (AreaA, AreaB) for them. My idea was to import both in `AppModule`, including shared ressources like Pipes (which can cause trouble here).

So for testing purpose, I created a Module called `ModuleA`

```
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
         HomeComponent
    ],

    imports: [
        UniversalModule, // Must be first import. This automatically imports BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule too.

        RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        ])
    ]
})

export class ModuleAModule {}
```

It's imported in the `AppModule` like this

```
import { ModuleAModule } from './module-a/module-a.module';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './shared/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { AppComponent } from './shared/app/app.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent
    ],

    imports: [
        UniversalModule, // Must be first import. This automatically imports BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule too.
        ModuleAModule
    ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

This gave me an exception

> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Template
>   parse errors: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message.

The `<router-outlet>`tag is used in the `app.component`as placeholder for the main content. But its working when I set the routes in the main app module like this

```
imports: [
    UniversalModule, // Must be first import. This automatically imports BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule too.
    ParentAreaModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        {path: 'home',component:HomeComponent}

    ])
]
```

This would force me to define all routes in the `app.module`. It requires imports to all my components across different modules, which seems to be a mess for me. I would like to set the routes in the sub-modules itselfs. The best solution would be an automatically added prefix for each module (like **module-a** for the first module).

Comment: Have you looled into feature modules and shared modules in angular? i guess that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { ModuleAModule } from './module-a/module-a.module';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './shared/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { AppComponent } from './shared/app/app.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent
    ],

    imports: [
        UniversalModule, // Must be first import. This automatically imports BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule too.
        ModuleAModule,
        RouterModule
    ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: you forgot to add RouterModule in your imports array.. this should work for you..

Comment: That gave me an `DI Error`. But your hint was right. I found out that `RouterModule` has to be replaced by `RouterModule.forRoot([])` to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of feature module if you have many features and want a separation in your app module.
Shared modules are modules which are common features between your application.
Core modules are modules which further split the app modules into things that are only specific to app module.

My suggestion will be to first develop the app and then look for modules and split them up.