# Inherit imports from parent module to child module in Angular2

Tags: angular, single-page-application, angular2-modules

I made an Angular2 app like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178088/import-modules-in-the-appmodule-for-separation-of-concerns-in-angular2/). It has two components (A,B) which are imported by the global `app.module`. My idea was, to include shared modules in `app.module`, so I don't need to mess up every module with redundant code. I want to do that for example with the `FormsModule`. So in the `app.module` I have

```
imports: [
    UniversalModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    AModule
    RouterModule.forRoot([])
],

exports: [FormsModule]
```

But in the A module I got the exception `Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'select'.` which seems caused by the missing `FormsModule`. It only works, when I import the `FormsModule`in every child module too using `imports: [FormsModule]`. That's exactly what I want to avoid.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925454/how-to-inherit-a-module-from-another-module-in-angular2), I tried to import the `AppModule` in the child module A. This doesn't work and give me the exception `Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AModule'`

How can I inherit the imports to child modules? I need this for pipes, too.

Answer (score 9):

Just create a feature module (or shared module) that exports the  components, directives, and pipes, that are usually used together and import this module to modules where you want to use any of these.

There is no way to make components, directives, or pipes available globally. They need to be added to imports of every module where they are used.
All you can do is combine modules and make them available by importing only a single or few modules.

Comment: You can import any module you want into another module except parent modules. That is *very* weird. I don't think using child modules is a good idea at all. It makes me want to flatten everything and avoid using child modules altogether so I can just import whatever I need.

Answer (score 8):

Seems that this can only be done using a shared module, which collects the shared imports, like @Günter Zöchbauer said. I found [an example in the official docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module), which I used as a base to create my shared module for doing this:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { ObjectKeysPipe } from './../shared/pipes/object-keys.pipe';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [
        ObjectKeysPipe
    ],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ObjectKeysPipe
    ]
})
export class GlobalSharedModule{}
```

This shares a custom pipe from me (`ObjectKeysPipe`) and both widely used `CommonModule` and `FormModule`. The idea of reducing redudant mess worked. In my application modules, I don't need to add a bunch of imports/declarations. Instead, I only need to import my shared module like this:

```
import { GlobalSharedModule } from './../shared/global-shared.module';
@ngModule({
    imports: GlobalSharedModule
})
```

Comment: One goal is to NOT use chains upon chains of `./../../../../../` to import modules. Any way to do that?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell In your `tsconfig.json` under `compilerOptions` and then `paths` you may declare a path like `"store": ["src/store.ts"]`. See [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping)